# Solve $ y’’ - 3 \frac{cosx}{sinx}y’ + (\frac{3}{sin^2x}-2)y = 0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

At the interval $(0, \pi)$ solve:

$$
y’’ - 3 \frac{cosx}{sinx}y’ + (\frac{3}{sin^2x}-2)y = 0
$$

If it is known that $\sin x$ Is a solution to the ODE.

---

What i tried:

I wanted to use the known solution in order to reduce the order of the ODE.

Setting:

$$
y = \sin x z
$$

Getting:

$$
y’ = \cos x z + \sin xz’
$$
$$
y’’ = -\sin xz +2cosxz’ + sinxz’’
$$

Implementing those derivatives into the ODE we get:

$$
-sinxz + 2cosxz’ + sinxz’’ - 3\frac{cosx}{sinx}(cosx + sinxz’) + (\frac{3}{sin^2x} - 2)sinxz = 0
$$

Finally getting to:

$$
sin^2xz’’ - sin2xz’ - 3z + 3 = 0
$$

The problem is that the order of the ODE has not changed, namely, it is still 2nd order ODE.

I tried to look for technical errors, but failed in finding.

So, what did i do wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: When I worked it out I got $\sin(x)z^{\prime\prime}-\cos(x)z^\prime=0$ with the coefficient of the $z$ term equaling $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient of the $z$ term should be

$$ -\sin(x)-3\frac{\cos^2(x)}{\sin(x)}+\frac{3}{\sin(x)}-2\sin(x) $$

which reduces to

$$ -3\sin(x)+3\sin(x)=0 $$

The coefficient of the $z^\prime$ term should be

$$ 2\cos(x)-3\cos(x)=-\cos(x) $$

So you get

$$ \sin(x)z^{\prime\prime}-\cos(x)z^\prime=0 $$

Letting $u=z^\prime$ reduces to a first order equation and you proceed accordingly.